# C# Interface that needs to be implemented by a third-party

Tags: c#, interface, api-design

I'm developing an API for third-party users and I'm stuck:

The API will look like the following:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Init(IComponent component);

    ...
}
```

The interface needs to be implemented by the third-party, but the Init method will be called by us. My problem is that I will pass an IComponent instance to them, which they can use in the Init method, but they should not use anywhere else.

Is it possible to do such a runtime check that they did not save it, or organize this kind of behaviour somehow that will make it impossible to use that IComponent instance out of the Init method?

Comment: You will expose IComponent interface to client app. They can create ANY class that implements it. So there is no way you can stop them from saving/casting ICOmponent to there own versions.

Comment: Secondly - If IComponent is your secret recipe - why are you exposing it?

Comment: It's not really a secret recipe. In the real scenario the IComponent is something through which they can provide some configuration, which will be merged to the global configuration. If they use the IComponent in the Init method then their config will be merged, but if they save it and will use it somewhere else, it will have no effect at all.

Comment: The third party code needs to implement `IComponent` and use it in `Init` method. That's the only thing you need to worry. If they implement the interface in a class and use that class to do something else in the code, you should not be bothered by that. If third party wants to use your code then they must your interface. Without that it will not work for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can directly control how Init() is implemented anywhere. However, your IComponent can be as sneaky as it needs to be, doing something like the code below will make it impossible for plugins to use the instance after the fact.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class Component : IComponent
{
    bool flag;

    public DoSomething()
    {
        if( flag )
            throw new NotSupportedException( "Operation not supported anymore." );
        // Do something normal during Init().
    }

    internal void MarkCOmplete()
    {
        flag = true;
    }
}

....

void Initialize()
{
    var component = new Component();

    foreach(var plugin in plugins)
    {
        plugin.Init(component);
    }
    component.MarkComplete();
}
```